# Start up error in App Engine - Jersey

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey

I am trying to prototype using Jersey in App Engine. When I deploy my application to {app}.appspot.com, I can see the following errors:

```
2013-08-06 08:19:52.749
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomFeedProvider, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomFeedProvider
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-5fd4a6aad8a8feef(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:256)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:131)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1310)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/syndication/io/FeedException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2447)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-5fd4a6aad8a8feef(Request.java)
    ... 41 more
```

The following is the settings in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.tattva.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The following jars are in my Build path.

```
    asm-3.1.jar
    jaxb-api-2.2.4.jar
    stax-api-1.0-2.jar
    jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.jar
    jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar
    jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.jar
    jackson-xc-1.7.1.jar
    jettison-1.1.jar
    activation-1.1.jar
    jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar
    jersey-client-1.8.jar
    jersey-core-1.8.jar
    jersey-json-1.8.jar
    jersey-server-1.8.jar
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with exactly the same error. I started playing with the jersey libraries and finally I downloaded the last version of jersey 1.9.1 as zip file, and the jar file as well :
https://jersey.java.net/download.html

Now in the project I have:
jersey-bundle-1.19.1.jar
jersey-multipart-1.19.1.jar
jersey-atom-abdera-1.19.1.jar

Now there is not start up error.

Answer (score 2):

As this question still gets views 3 years later, the root cause of this error is the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/syndication/io/FeedException
```

This is in turned caused by a missing dependency for the`com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException` class, which is part of the [ROME framework](https://github.com/rometools/rome) for RSS and Atom feeds. It is needed by the `com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomFeedProvider` class in Jersey.

Following the Maven Central link from the project page, you can add the following dependency to your project to resolve this issue:

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
    <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle:**

```
compile 'com.rometools:rome:1.7.1'
```

Or simply [download the JAR directly](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/rometools/rome/1.7.1/) and add it to your project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using some of the RSS utilities from the Rome project, and yet you don't have that jar in your path.

I think that you can get the jar at:  https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Home