# Jersey throwing exception in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey

I am trying to use mail gun API for sending messages.

```
public Map sendMail(String toMailId, String subject, String html) {
  String useremail = CommonAttributesHelper.getLoggedInUser(getThreadLocalRequest());
  log.info("Logged in user email is " + useremail);

  Preconditions.checkNotNull(toMailId);
  Preconditions.checkNotNull(useremail);
  Preconditions.checkNotNull(html);

  UserMessagesAndErrors ume = ThreadLocalObjects.getThreadLocalUserMessagesAndErrors().get();
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  map.put("ume", ume);

  Client client = Client.create();
  client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("api", "key-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));

  WebResource webResource =
      client.resource("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org/messages");

  MultivaluedMapImpl formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
  formData.add("from", useremail);
  formData.add("to", toMailId);
  formData.add("subject", subject);
  formData.add("html", html);

  webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
  ume.addMessage("Mail sent successfully");
  return map; 
}
```

It works fine in local,  but i am getting the exception in the remote google app engine server even though mail is sent. I have copied the error stack trace and pasted below.

```
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomFeedProvider, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilizedjava.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomFeedProvider
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-274b4b6665811552(Request.java)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:289)
at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:132)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:124)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:283)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:163)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:160)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:673)
at com.veersoft.gwt.server.CommonGwtServiceImpl.sendMail(CommonGwtServiceImpl.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:44)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.veersoft.filter.ResetUserMessagesAndErrorsFilter.doFilter(ResetUserMessagesAndErrorsFilter.java:30)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:439)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:446)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:310)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:302)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:443)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
... 63 moreCaused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/syndication/io/FeedException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2621)
... 63 moreCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.syndication.io.FeedException
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-274b4b6665811552(Request.java)
... 63 more
```

Also I am using the standard Jersey dependencies which [GAE recommended](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/sending-emails-with-mailgun), 
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any idea how to solve the issue? I came across setting a property in a file like this `jersey.config.multipart.bufferThreshold=-1` but it didn't really help. I'm using Spring / Maven / Google app engine.

Comment: @MaxZooZoo Mailgun support team said that they are not rejecting the connection and also i couldn't figure out the issue. So I dropped mailgun and started using [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com), also GAE has provided some good docs about using the API. See here [Sending Email with SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid)

Comment: Thanks, I switched to SMTP on mailgun and everything is going smooth. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start up error in App Engine - Jersey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084676/start-up-error-in-app-engine-jersey)